# How to find percentage change in income from month to month?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a sample table of IDs with income and months and would like to get the percent change in income from month to month. A change of income from 0 to something else is not valid.

```
ID  INCOME  MONTH
1   150     02/2017
1   100     01/2017
2   25      03/2017
2   75      02/2017
2   50      01/2017
3   100     03/2017
3   0       02/2017
4   100     03/2017
4   25      02/2017
4   50      01/2017
5   0       02/2017
5   0       01/2017
6   100     02/2017
6   0       01/2017
6   50      12/2016
7   100     11/2016
7   100     10/2016
```

% Change = ((New Income – Original Income)/Original Income) *100

So for ID #1, for 01/2017-02/2017, that's ((150-100)/100)*100=50%. For ID #2, for 02/2017-03/2017, that's ((25-75)/75)*100 = -67%, and for 01/2017-02/2017, that's ((75-50)/50)*100=50%.

Intended results:

```
ID  Period              % Change
1   01/2017-02/2017     50
2   01/2017-02/2017     50
2   02/2017-03/2017     -67
4   01/2017-02/2017     -50
4   02/2017-03/2017     300
6   12/2016-01/2017     -100
7   10/2016-11/2016     0
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `MONTH` column has the `DATE` data type:

```
SELECT id,
       TO_CHAR( prev_month, 'MM/YYYY' ) || '-' || TO_CHAR( month, 'MM/YYYY' ) As period,
       100 * income / prev_income - 100 AS "% Change"
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LAG( month  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month ) AS prev_month,
         LAG( income ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month ) AS prev_income
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE  ADD_MONTHS( prev_month, 1 ) = month
AND    prev_income > 0;
```

**Update**:

```
SELECT id,
       TO_CHAR( prev_month, 'MM/YYYY' ) || '-' || TO_CHAR( month, 'MM/YYYY' ) As period,
       100 * income / prev_income - 100 AS "% Change"
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         TO_DATE( month, 'MM/YYYY' ) AS month,
         income,
         LAG( TO_DATE( month, 'MM/YYYY' )  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TO_DATE( month, 'MM/YYYY' ) ) AS prev_month,
         LAG( income                       ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TO_DATE( month, 'MM/YYYY' ) ) AS prev_income
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE  ADD_MONTHS( prev_month, 1 ) = month
AND    prev_income > 0;
```

Comment: thanks! what if the month column is a character type, and in the format MM/YYYY?

Comment: @DaveJabbz Updated - just wrap the instances of `month` in the inner query in `TO_DATE( month, 'MM/YYYY' )`.